# PHP fopen write filename with php variable and file extension

Tags: php, fopen

I have a variable `$id` from URL parameter that contains a name ID-number like `1234.5Z`

How can I use `fopen` to write a file called `1234.5Z.json`?

I tried the following syntax:

```
$fp = fopen($id+'.json', 'w');
```

But I end up with a file named 1243.5

Comment: In php we concatenate strings with `.` (dot)

Comment: some one has spent to much time on javascript. in php its a `.` not a `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you don't concatenate strings using the `+` sign, you use the `.` instead.

So, your code will look more like

```
$fp = fopen($id . '.json', 'w');
```

---

What happens when you were using the `+`, is that PHP was thinking you were doing an arithmetic operation, and thus, it does it's best to parse the number within the first string, and as a result `1234.5Z -> 1234.5`, and `.json -> 0`, and therein `1234.5 + 0 = 1234.5`, which then will be used as the string for the name.